# Payment splitter for ERC1155 multi-token

Tags: contract-design, erc-1155, royalties

I'll keep it simple for the question. Let's say I have a multi-token ERC1155 smart contract containing 10 NFTs. I would like the split the revenue from secondary sales, since opensea (and the EIP2981 royalties standard) only takes one address for the royalties, the way to go seems to be using a Payment splitter.

Each of these 10 NFTs would have a different split percentage and different receivers.

For example, I will call these shares:

- NFT-1: 10% for userA and 90% userB
- NFT-2: 15% userB, 35% userC and 50% userD
- etc.

I would like some guidance regarding the design of the whole thing.
I was thinking of:

- Using the minimal proxy standard EIP-1167 to implement clone/proxy of a payment splitter base contract
  Here is the part where I am not sure:
- These proxy contract would be initialized with custom mapping of the shares for a specific token id

So the whole process would require:

- PaymentSplitterImplementation.sol
- PaymentSplitterFactory.sol
- PaymentSplitterProxies.sol (multiples)
- BaseContract1155.sol

Does this make sense? Is this feasible? Am I overcomplexifying my solution.
The goal would be to optimize gas fees and deployment fees.

Thank you for your answers!